# React изменение состояния

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

В родительском компоненте есть стейт со значением state: true. Из него выходят дочерний компонент Auth, из него в свою очередь Form. В родительском компоненте есть функция изменения сетейта на false. Я прокидываю ее пропсом в Auth, там делаю еще одну функцию, которая вызывает предыдущую, меняющую сетейт. Эту функцию я пробрасываю в Form и там вызываю. Что я делаю не так? Возможно ли одну функцию пробрасывать через все компоненты?

Компонент App

```
 state = {
    AuthVisible: true,
}

onSubmited = () => {
    this.setState({AuthVisible: false});
}

<div className="col-lg-3">
        {this.state.AuthVisible ? 
        <Auth 
        onSubmited={this.onSubmited} 
        onRegister={this.onRegister} /> : 
        <UserInfo 
        userName={this.state.userName}
        userСompany={this.state.userСompany}
        userId={this.state.userId}/>}
        </div>
```

Компонент  Auth

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onClickRegister = this.onClickRegister.bind(this);
  }


 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmited();
  }

render() {                            
    return (

      <div>
      <div className="authForm">ЛИЧНЫЙ КАБИНЕТ</div>
      <Form 
      onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} 
      onChange= {this.handleChange} 
      onRegister= {this.onClickRegister} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


Компонент Form

 return (
     <div>
        <form className="formAuth" onSubmit={onSubmit} onChange={onChange}>
         <div>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Личный e-mail" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" />
        </div>
        <div>

          <input type="checkbox" name="alienPc" />
          <label htmlFor="alienPc">Чужой компьютер</label>
          </div>
          <button className="btn btn-primary">Войти</button>
          <a href="#" className="forgot">Забыли пароль?</a>
      </form>
        <button onClick={onRegister} className="btn btn-danger btn-block">
        {true ? 'Рег' : 'Глав'}
        </button>

      </div>
      );
```

Это работает, но мне кажется я что то делаю не так.
И второй вопрос, который я не могу решить: строка в Form

```
<button onClick={onRegister} className="btn btn-danger btn-block">
{true ? 'Рег' : 'Глав'}
```

Что написать вместо true, что бы надпись менялась? Я не могу добраться до родительского стейта, хотя уже не раз пытался пробрасывать его пропсами через всех детей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функцию и state можно прокидывать через все дочерние компоненты.

```js
<Auth 
  onSubmited={this.onSubmited} 
  onRegister={this.onRegister} 
/>


// В копоненте Auth
<Form 
  onSubmited = {this.props.onSubmited} 
  ...
/>
```

и потом в From с this.props достаёшь функцию onSubmited.

state так же перекидываются.